# Find the integral solutions for the following diophantine equation: $85 + 1156k = m^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

My question is the same as above. I am still a novice in Diophantine Equations(I only know linear Diophantine Equations) and Number Theory so I do not have much notion of what to do to solve this question. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: @AlexSilva I am not stuck. I simply do not know how to solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$85+1156k=17(5+17\cdot4k)\implies17|m\implies17^2|m^2$

But $17^2\nmid85$ and $17^2|1156$

Comment: So, no solutions possible